# How to add rich snippet in a website?

Tags: asp.net, xml, seo, google-search, rich-snippets

I am getting a XML data through an review website but i need to add a rich snippet to this so google can show the ratings but i am unable to find the exact example

here is the part of an XML

```
 <reviewDetails>
    <reviewDetail>
        <score>5</score>
        <scoremax>5</scoremax>
        <text>
            <![CDATA[Something something something.]]>
        </text>
        <user>
            <![CDATA[Person]]>
        </user>
        <id>1494839</id>
        <createdate>20160420</createdate>
        <beveeltAan>
            <![CDATA[ja]]>
        </beveeltAan>
        <reviewID>1494839</reviewID>
        <reviewDatum>20160420</reviewDatum>
        <questions>
            <question>
                <label>
                    <![CDATA[Verkooptraject]]>
                </label>
                <score>-1</score>
                <order>1</order>
                <type>
                    <![CDATA[score]]>
                </type>
            </question>
            <question>
                <label>
                    <![CDATA[Informatie op SiteToGo.nl]]>
                </label>
                <score>-1</score>
                <order>2</order>
                <type>
                    <![CDATA[score]]>
                </type>
            </question>
            <question>
                <label>
                    <![CDATA[Communicatie website bouwer]]>
                </label>
                <score>-1</score>
                <order>3</order>
                <type>
                    <![CDATA[score]]>
                </type>
            </question>
            <question>
                <label>
                    <![CDATA[Bereikbaarheid]]>
                </label>
                <score>-1</score>
                <order>4</order>
                <type>
                    <![CDATA[score]]>
                </type>
            </question>
            <question>
                <label>
                    <![CDATA[Snelheid oplevering]]>
                </label>
                <score>-1</score>
                <order>5</order>
                <type>
                    <![CDATA[score]]>
                </type>
            </question>
            <question>
                <label>
                    <![CDATA[Prijs-/kwaliteit verhouding]]>
                </label>
                <score>-1</score>
                <order>6</order>
                <type>
                    <![CDATA[score]]>
                </type>
            </question>
        </questions>
        <kooptvakeronline></kooptvakeronline>
        <geslacht>
            <![CDATA[vrouw]]>
        </geslacht>
        <leeftijd>0</leeftijd>
        <gekochtproduct></gekochtproduct>
        <companyResponse></companyResponse>
        <filterCode></filterCode>
    </reviewDetail>
    <reviewDetail>
```

so how can I add rich snippet in this xml so google will able to show the ratings on my website.

Comment: Do you know/read that Google Search supports structured data in XML? That would surprise me; they typically only support structured data in web pages, i.e., (X)HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show some progress before we can offer advice.
Here is what I recommend you do.

1. Go to schema.org (http://schema.org/docs/full.html) and decide which Type(s) is relevant to your XML data.
2. Once you have determined the Type(s), look for properties that mean the same as the terms used in your XML source.
3. Work with the relevant examples on schema.org and apply them to your modified data (steps 1 and 2).
4. Show the results of steps 1-3 and ask for further clarification about how to improve your results or deal with error messages revealed by the Google Structured Data Testing Tool (https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/).